# If $c$ divides $d$ and $c$ does not equal $d$, show that there exists two integers whose greatest common divisor is $c$ and who add to $d$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Basically show that if $c$ divides $d$, and assuming they are not equal this implies there exist an $a$ and $b$ such that $\gcd(a, b) = c$ and $a + b = d$. I cannot figure this question out.

Comment: There's no need for the "c not equal to d" hypothesis here, unless $a$ and $b$ are required to be *positive* integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$d=kc=(k-1)c+c$$
as $k\neq1$, you have your sum.

Answer (score 1):

Given $c|d$ 
So we can say there exists an integer $r$ such that $d=cr$ 
Now say $r$ is represented as the sum of 2 integers $l$ and $m$ such that both $l,m < r$ and $l$ and $m$ are co-prime. 
So, $$l+m=r$$ or, $$cl+cm=cr$$ or, $$a+b=d$$ where $gcd(a,b)=c$. 
So, there exists 2 integers a and b such that $gcd(a,b)=c$ and $a+b=d$.
Here $a=cl$ and $b=cm$